# How to fix array boolean error using filter function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to use solve the Boolean error using filter

I used a filter array to solve the Boolean problem of iterating arrays. It worked for a simple list, however it is again showing error when used to take only those numbers which are greater than zero from an array. The method used to populate the array is drawing samples from a standard normal distribution.

```
   arr2 = np.array(list(filter(lambda x:x>0,rand_num)))
   arr2
```

```
<ipython-input-80-af65f7c09d82> in <module>
      1 rand_num = np.random.randn(5,5)
----> 2 arr2 = np.array(list(filter(lambda x:x>0,rand_num)))
      3 arr2
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: `rand_num` is likely a multidimensional array?

Comment: Look at `[x>0 for x in rand_num]` ibn the 2 cases.

Comment: Please provide an array sample and how would the desired output look like.

Comment: What is a filter array? What is the Boolean problem of iterating arrays? Even more important, what is `rand_num`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a 2d array of floats:

```
In [60]: rand_num = np.random.randn(5,5)                                                                     
In [61]: rand_num                                                                                            
Out[61]: 
array([[ 1.89811694,  0.44414858, -2.52994217, -0.17974148, -0.91167712],
       [ 0.06534556,  0.04677172, -0.81580021,  0.08053772, -0.55459303],
       [ 0.41316473, -0.35859064,  1.28860476, -0.22666389,  0.97562048],
       [ 0.29465373,  0.71143579, -0.55552921,  0.37660919,  0.31482962],
       [ 0.2768353 , -1.32999438,  0.0594767 ,  1.50255302,  0.08658897]])
```

We can select the ones that are >0 with a boolean mask:

```
In [62]: rand_num>0                                                                                          
Out[62]: 
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True,  True]])
In [63]: rand_num[rand_num>0]                                                                                
Out[63]: 
array([1.89811694, 0.44414858, 0.06534556, 0.04677172, 0.08053772,
       0.41316473, 1.28860476, 0.97562048, 0.29465373, 0.71143579,
       0.37660919, 0.31482962, 0.2768353 , 0.0594767 , 1.50255302,
       0.08658897])
```

Boolean indexing of a array produces a 1d array - because each row can vary in the number of True values.

`filter` like `map` iterates on the first dimension of the array:

```
In [64]: list(map(lambda x:x>0, rand_num))                                                                   
Out[64]: 
[array([ True,  True, False, False, False]),
 array([ True,  True, False,  True, False]),
 array([ True, False,  True, False,  True]),
 array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True]),
 array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True])]
```

same thing in list comprehension form:

```
In [65]: [x>0 for x in rand_num]                                                                             
Out[65]: 
[array([ True,  True, False, False, False]),
 array([ True,  True, False,  True, False]),
 array([ True, False,  True, False,  True]),
 array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True]),
 array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True])]
```

Notice how each element of the iteration is a numpy array of shape (5,).  That's what the `filter` is choking on.  It expects a simple True/False boolean, not an array.  Python `if` and `or` have the same problem.  (Actually I think it's `numpy` that's refusing to pass the multi-item array to the Python function that expects the scalar, and instead raises this ambiguity error.)

You could apply the `filter` to each row of `rand_num`:

```
In [66]: [list(filter(lambda x: x>0, row)) for row in rand_num]                                              
Out[66]: 
[[1.898116938827415, 0.4441485849428062],
 [0.06534556093009064, 0.04677172433407727, 0.08053772013844711],
 [0.41316473050686314, 1.2886047644946972, 0.9756204798856322],
 [0.2946537313273924,
  0.711435791237748,
  0.3766091899348284,
  0.31482961532956577],
 [0.27683530300005493,
  0.05947670354791034,
  1.502553021817318,
  0.0865889738396504]]
```

These are the same numbers as in `Out[63]`, but split up by row - with a different number of items in each.

The same thing in the @Willem Van Onsem's masked array format:

```
In [69]: np.ma.masked_array(rand_num, mask=rand_num <= 0)                                                    
Out[69]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[1.898116938827415, 0.4441485849428062, --, --, --],
        [0.06534556093009064, 0.04677172433407727, --,
         0.08053772013844711, --],
        [0.41316473050686314, --, 1.2886047644946972, --,
         0.9756204798856322],
        [0.2946537313273924, 0.711435791237748, --, 0.3766091899348284,
         0.31482961532956577],
        [0.27683530300005493, --, 0.05947670354791034, 1.502553021817318,
         0.0865889738396504]],
  mask=[[False, False,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True, False, False],
        [False,  True, False, False, False]],
  fill_value=1e+20)
```

Answer (score 3):

Likely `rand_num` is a multidimensional array. In taht case the elements (so `x`) will be an array as well. For `x > 0`, this is an array of `bool`s, but you can not say that an array of booleans is `True` or `False`. Imagine that an array contains two `True`s and three `False`s for example. Would you consider that `True` or not?

Using `filter(..)` is likely not necessary here. You can easily filter your array by subscripting it with an array of booleans:

```
arr2 = rand_num[rand_num > 0]
```

For example:

```
>>> rand_num[rand_num > 0]
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

or we can construct a masked array if we want to retains the shape:

```
arr2 = np.ma.masked_array(rand_num, mask=rand_num <= 0)
```

This will yield:

```
>>> np.ma.masked_array(rand_num, mask=rand_num <= 0)
masked_array(
  data=[[--, 1, 1, --, --],
        [--, --, 1, --, --],
        [--, 1, 2, --, --],
        [--, --, --, 1, --],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
  mask=[[ True, False, False,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
        [ True, False, False,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True, False,  True],
        [False, False, False, False, False]],
  fill_value=999999)
```

Comment: `rand_num = np.random.randn(5,5)`. This will flatten it.

Comment: @CristiFati: correct, but even a two level filter will need to flatten it: how would you for exampe construct a new array with one row having two elements and another one having four elements?